# Javascript and function prototype assignment

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I've always assumed that the prototype of a function was shared among all the objects, in a sense by reference. So if you change the value of a property of the prototype, all objects that share that prototype have the values change for them as well.  So for instance below it seems that instead of the property bar being shared between all objects, it is copied.  Is this right?  Are the properties of the prototype of the constructor simply copied to all the class objects as they are created, or are they shared by linkage?

```
function foo()
{
     this.bar = 1;
}
function derived() { }
derived.prototype = new foo()

object1 = new derived()
object2 = new derived()

object1.bar = 2;
//but notice if I had said here derived.prototype.bar = 3, object1.bar would still equal 2 but object2.bar would equal 3
alert(object2.bar) // this prints 1;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you assign `object1.bar = 2`, you are creating an *own property* on `object1`, this property exist only in that object instance, and it has nothing to do with its prototype.

This property on `object1` will *shadow* the value of the one existing on `derived.prototype`, this means that when you lookup `object1.bar`, it will find a value directly existing on that object.

On the other side, if you lookup `object2.bar`, this object doesn't have an own `bar` property, so the property lookup will search on the object this one inherits from (`derived.prototype`) and it will find the value `1`.

Your object structure looks something like this:

```
 object1
 --------
| bar: 2 | -----------------
 --------                   |         derived.prototype
                            |        ----------
                            |------> | bar: 1  | --    foo.prototype
 object2 (no own properties)|        ----------   |   ------------------
 --------                   |                     -> | constructor: foo |
|        | -----------------                          ------------------
 --------                                                    |
                                                             v
                                                     ------------------
                                                    | Object.prototype |
                                                     ------------------
                                                             |
                                                             v
                                                            null
```

Where the `--->` lines denote the internal `[[Prototype]]` link that expresses inheritance.

Comment: ohhh, makes perfect sense, so as long as I don't re-assign it, it refers to the inherited property, so once I assign it become a own property?

Comment: I got it now, that diagram helped a lot, thank you so much, your answer was awesome :-)

Comment: @rubixibuc, right, once you assign it, it will become an own property and it will *shadow* any value up in the prototype chain. Also note that the `[[Prototype]]` link cannot be changed once an object is created, for example, after creating `object1` and `object2`, you reassign a different object to `derived.prototype` this won't affect the properties inherited by those two objects.

Comment: @rubixibuc I updated the diagram, I had forgotten `foo.prototype` :)

Answer (score 2):

For example, you have code:

```
function Animal() {
}
Animal.prototype.name="animal";

function Dog() {
}
Dog.prototype = new Animal
Dog.prototype.constructor=Dog;
Dog.prototype.name="dog";

object1 = new Animal();
object2 = new Dog();
```

As a result you have two object instances, that looked as (you can check this for example in Chrome devtools or FF firebug or...):

```
object1:
  __proto__: (is ref into an Animal.prototype object)
    constructor: function Animal()
    name: "animal"
    __proto__: Object (is ref into an Object.prototype object)

object2:
  __proto__: (is ref into an Dog.prototype object)
    constructor: function Dog()
    name: "dog"
    __proto__: (is ref into an Animal.prototype object)
      constructor: function Animal()
      name: "animal"
      __proto__: (is ref into an Object.prototype object)
```

When you run next code (for example):

```
alert(object1.name); // displayed "animal"
alert(object2.name); // displayed "dog"
```

What happened? 1) Javascript looked for property name in object instance (in `object1` or `object2`). 2) When not found, it looked up in object instance **proto** property (that is same as prototype of class function). 3) When not founct it looked in **proto** of **proto** and next and next while not found `name` property and others **proto** found. If as result of search property is found, then value is returned, if not found, then `undefined` returned.

What happened if you execute next code:

```
object2.name = "doggy";
```

As a result you have for object2:

```
object2:
  name: "doggy"
  __proto__: (is ref into an Dog.prototype object)
    constructor: function Dog()
    name: "dog"
    __proto__: (is ref into an Animal.prototype object)
      constructor: function Animal()
      name: "animal"
      __proto__: (is ref into an Object.prototype object)
```

Property is assigned directly into instance object, but prototype object remains unchanged. And when you execute:

```
alert(object1.name); // displayed "animal"
alert(object2.name); // displayed "doggy"
```

---

When you need to create|change *shared* property of class, you can use one from next algoritms:
1)

```
Animal.prototype.secondName="aaa";
alert(object1.secondName); // displayed "aaa"
alert(object2.secondName); // displayed "aaa"
Animal.prototype.secondName="bbb";
alert(object1.secondName); // displayed "bbb"
alert(object2.secondName); // displayed "bbb"
// but
Animal.prototype.secondName="ccc";
object1.secondName="ddd";
alert(object1.secondName); // displayed "ccc"
alert(object2.secondName); // displayed "ddd"
```

2)
Create property of type `object` in prototype of function class and assign values to properties of this object.

```
Animal.prototype.propObject={thirdName:"zzz"};
alert(object1.propObject.thirdName); // displayed "zzz"
alert(object2.propObject.thirdName); // displayed "zzz"
Animal.prototype.propObject.thirdName="yyy";
alert(object1.propObject.thirdName); // displayed "yyy"
alert(object2.propObject.thirdName); // displayed "yyy"
object1.propObject.thirdName="xxx";
alert(object1.propObject.thirdName); // displayed "xxx"
alert(object2.propObject.thirdName); // displayed "xxx"
object2.propObject.thirdName="www";
alert(object1.propObject.thirdName); // displayed "www"
alert(object2.propObject.thirdName); // displayed "www"
```

Comment: Nicely Explained.